# Return stringstream from a function

Tags: c++, stringstream

Clearly I am missing something important about stringstreams in general here, but could someone explain why

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

stringstream foo() {
  stringstream ss;
  return ss;
}
```

Fails with

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ios:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:40,
             from rwalk.cpp:1:/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char,    std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h:790: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:47: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:75: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here 
/usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf:770: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:63: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:75: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringbuf(const std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’ first required here 
rwalk.cpp: In function ‘std::stringstream foo()’:
rwalk.cpp:12: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)’ first required here
```

How does one return a stringstream from a function properly? (edit: added the headers for a complete code snippet and fixed typo)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After correct the type-o in the return type (noted by Mahesh), your code will not compile in C++03 because `stringstream` is not copyable.  However if your compiler supports C++0x, turning that on allows your code to compile because `stringstream` is `MoveConstructible`.

Comment: I think it cannot compile even in C++11 without `std::move()`.

Comment: @PetrPervukhin: Why? According to 27.8.6 [stringstream.cons], `basic_stringstream` has a valid, accessible move constructor which will be used to move `ss` out of `foo`.  Is there some other reason you see that makes the code not valid C++11?

Comment: I can say about C++03, that if there is no copy constructor in class A, you cannot write `A a = A()`, even if compiler can apply copy constructor elision. So I'm not sure that compiler can replace copy construction with move construction in this example.

Comment: Excuse me. I tried it in Coliru, it works fine. So my next question for google and SO will be "why?". =)

Comment: @PetrPervukhin: See  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Moving%20from%20local%20values for rationale.

Answer (score 12):

You can't return a stream from a function by value, because that implies you'd have to *copy* the stream. C++ streams are not copyable.

Comment: I may be asking the wrong question - but why can't I copy the stream?

Comment: @Hooked it's not obvious what the semantics of stream copies would be. When you write into one copy, should the write also occur in the other? When you close one stream, should the other close as well? When you change one stream's locale, should the other change as well? In correct programs you shouldn't have the _need_ to copy a stream.

Answer (score 7):

Old question but I believe that the correct way to achieve what you want is to use the [stringstream::str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) method that returns a string object with a copy of the current contents in the stream buffer.

Here is an example with `string str() const;`.

```
std::string foo() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "add whatever you want to the stream" << 12 << ' ' << 13.4;
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo();
    return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
add whatever you want to the stream 12 13.4
```

Comment: a huge lot of thanks to actually help we SOLVE the problem!! :D

Answer (score 3):

While it does not work in C++03, it should work in C++11. However, current compilers may still have problems (due to the lack of full C++11 compatibility), e.g. the above code will not compile in g++ 4.6.1

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 you'll have to either pass the stringstream as a parameter by non-const reference or return just the resulting string (`ss.str()`), as you can't copy the stream.

Answer (score -2):

You have to include `sstream` and have `std::stringstream` instead of `stringstream`.